# Firebase auth onAuthStateChanged resolving to null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the current user UID from a Firebase database - a simple task in principle. I'm following the guide for managing users from the firebase documentation but I still am unable to get a solution. Everywhere I see that firebase.auth().currentuser will not be defined during initialisation - ok great. I use a listener instead, and the listener fires as it should. But for some reason when it fires, the value of user is null.

```
export default class ShoppingCategories extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        GeoFire: new GeoFire(firebase.database().ref('stores-geo').push()),
        stores: exstores,
        brands: [],
        storesSelected: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getStoreTile();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) =>{
        if(user){
            this.locateStores(user);
        }else{
            console.log("No user found: "+user);
        }
    });
}

...
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I get

```
No user found: null
```

printed to the console.

Comment: Are you certain that you have a logged-in user? Firebase will return null if there is no authenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. My service worker was causing the page to be served from cache. I removed the service worker caching feature which fixed the problem. Not exactly sure how to fix this long term right now but will update once I solve.